# Pandas dataframe create new column based on list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.4

Consider this dataframe:

```
In [0]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Num': [1, 2, 3, 4] * 5})
In [1]: len(df)
Out[1]: 20
```

I want to create a new column based on list of tuples: for example:

```
In [2]: tup = [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (4, 1)]
In [3]: len(tup)
Out[3]: 4
```

Where `df['Num'] ==` to the first item in tuple, I want to add the second value to the new column.

This is the example of desired output:

```
    Num    bin
 0    1      0
 1    2      1
 2    3      0
 3    4      1
 4    1      0
 5    2      1
 6    3      0
...
19    4      1
```

I tried this code to achieve this result:

```
df['bin'] = [j for l in df['Num'] for i,j in tup if i == l]
```

The result is ok, but I got a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So, what is the best approache to copy values to a new dataframe column?

Comment: Hm, I don't get that warning. What version of pandas?

Comment: `pandas==0.18.1`. Actually, warning appears in a large dataset. When I ran this example, warning didn't appear. But I am looking for a best approache instead a list comprehesion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an all-Pandas approach; convert your tuples into a dataframe and merge it with the original data:

```
tuples_as_df = pd.DataFrame(tup, columns=['dummy','bin'])
df = df.merge(tuples_as_df, how='left', left_on='Num', right_on='dummy')
del df['dummy'] # The merge key, not needed anymore
#    Num  bin
#0     1    0
#1     2    1
#2     3    0
#3     4    1
#4     1    0
#5     2    1
#....
```

Comment: I like this idea better than mine +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is better but you can put the tuple in a dictionary and use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
tup = [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (4, 1)]
d = {k:v for k,v in tup}
df['bin'] = df.applymap(lambda x: d[x])
```

Comment: I got this error `KeyError: (1, 'occurred at index Item')`. I liked the idea of using `applymap`.